# openpyxl - Check if sheet contains errors

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have workbook and one sheet in the workbook:

```py
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("path/to/workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

How can I **return all cells that contain an error** in the spreadsheet?
I know there could be different types of errors (formula error, N/As, data validation error etc...), just trying to see what's possible throught the Python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be so. Reading an excel file, taking only cell values and comparing them with a list of errors.

```
test.xlsx
```

[image]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

ERROR_CODES = ('#NULL!', '#DIV/0!', '#VALUE!', '#REF!', '#NAME?', '#NUM!', '#N/A')

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = wb.active
cell_error = [ws.cell(row=i, column=j) for j in range(1, ws.max_column + 1)
              for i in range(1, ws.max_row + 1)
              if ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value in ERROR_CODES]

print(cell_error)

-----------------------------------------

[<Cell 'Лист1'.A3>, <Cell 'Лист1'.C1>, <Cell 'Лист1'.C2>]
```

Comment: Sounds like what's needed but partially because this won't return data validation errors - any idea if that can be done? (edit your answer?)

Comment: @michal111
Yes, there is a validity check https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html#other-validation-examples. There are examples, you will just need to add your validation rules.